# How to get a number of probability distributions "averaged"?

Tags: matlab, probability, data-analysis

Let us say I have 'n' vectors of data of unequal lengths. All of these vectors are similar (range, etc., see example below), and can be fitted into a specific probability distribution. How can we average out these distributions? Does it make sense? If yes, how do I go about programming it ?

For example:-
for n=2, for data1 of 400 samples, I get normal distribution with range 1 to 5, and mean 3 and standard deviation 0.75.

for data2 of 500 samples, I get normal distribution with range 0.95 to 5.2, and mean 3.05 and standard deviation 0.78.

Comment: Well, one way to look at this is to construct a mixture distribution in which the components are n sample distributions you have, and the mixing weights are the proportion of data in each sample. In the given example, mixing weights = [400/900, 500/900]. Mixture distributions are pretty easy to work with. There might already be some usable code for that, if not, it's not a big deal to write your own.

Comment: @RobertDodier   Thanks Robert for the comment. Intuitively, I would do the same. But, it turns out that it is a real thing. Also, I found that there is a MATLAB function serving my purpose. I was mostly concerned about it making any sense.